# Сколько раз можно отнимать?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Есть некое число N от него отнимаем сумму его цифр. Вопрос сколько раз можно отнимать?
обычный код

```
while n>0 do begin
    inc(k);
    x:=n;
     while x<>0 do 
     begin
      n := n - (x mod 10);
      x := x div 10;
     end;
```

не работает так как выходит за рамки 1 сек. Каким способом можно еще?

Comment: а если запустить на более мощном компьютером?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

на моем ноутбуке 100 миллионов считает чуть меньше секунды. Но нужно узнать верхнее ограничение, какие максимальные числа будут вводиться. Припустим, что это 2 в 32 (либо 2 в 31 - что логично и вписывается в стандартный тип integer).

Этот же код, будучи запущенным с 2 в 32 у меня отработал за 42 секунды.

А теперь начинаем ускорятся. Но так как это очень похоже на олимпиадную задачу, то тут можно применять различные грязные оптимизации, которые в промышленный код никогда не выкладывается.

Первое, что нужно помнить, это то, что если для любого числа проделать операцию вычитания из него его цифр, то полученное число будет кратно 9. Это очень легко доказывается, если знать правило проверки на делимость на 9. ( любое число делится на 9, если сумма его цифр делится на 9. Если не делится, то остаток от деления числа на 9 и суммы цифр, деленной на 9 совпадает. Поэтому разница числа и суммы его цифр будет кратна 9).

Модифицируем немного код и запускаем. Видим, что `n` проходят одну и ту же последовательность. (... 45 36 27 18 9 0). Исходя из этого, можно сделать предпросчет для определенных значений n и просто подставлять правильный ответ. Так как у меня расчет для максимально занимает 42 секунды, то просто подбираем 50 промежуточных значений, что бы в каждом диапазоне считалось не дольше 1 секунды (50 - с запасом).

Следующим этапом будем сокращать ещё на процентов 40%. Суммировать будем по два цифры за раз. Вот мой наробосок кода:

```
program subb;
// таблица сумм для двузначных чисел.
const h:array[0..99] of integer = (0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 , 16 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 , 16 , 17 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 , 16 , 17 , 18);
var n, k, x:int64; 
    l:int64;
begin
    // это такой трюк, что бы можно было передавать как параметр и с консоли вводить
    if paramcount < 1 then
        readln(n)
    else
        val(paramstr(1), n, k);
    k := 0;
    while n > 0 do begin
        if (n = 9999999) then begin // это первая проверка для ускорения
            n := 0;
            k := k+333582;
            continue;
        end;
        inc(k);
        x := n;
        //writeln('curr n = ', n);
        while x > 0 do begin
            l := x mod 100;
            n := n - h[l];
            x := x div 100;
        end;
    end;
    writeln(k);
end.
```

Этот код по сравнению с оригинальным уже работает в 2 раза быстрее. А если добавить немного опорных точек, то можно подогнать общее время.

Но я думаю, есть формула попроще. Если присмотреться к выводу, то видно, что в пределах первых 400 чисел прослеживается зависимость - количество вычетаний равно целой части от деления на 10  (плюс минус 1). Дальше нужно вычитать ещё какой-то поправочный коэффициент.

Comment: сравнил этот код со своим. мой быстрее вдвое получился. хотя с 9ками вариант интересен, да.

Comment: да, хорошая эта штука оптимизация если знаешь как ее применять, спасибо код действительно получился быстрым если добавить десяток проверок
0.031ms

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант.
Если взять integer, то каково бы ни было число вычитать каждый раз приходится не больше 100. Следовательно нам нет необходимости для больших чисел вычислять каждый раз сумму **всех** цифр, можно считать на каждой итерации сумму только трех последних цифр, а сумма более старших разрядов вычислена по крайней мере на несколько итераций. Таким образом количество вычислений можно сократить в разы.
Набросал тут на коленке, толком не проверял получились такие результаты...

```
  N      Вычитаний   Время  
2^31-1   54682584    3.744  
2^32    106102644    7.441
```

4 секунды для Int32 уже неплохо =)

Для int64 там будет не больше 180 на каждой итерации, т.е. те же уши.

ЗЫ Забыл написать, оригинальный код работает больше 14 секунд для 2^31-1